# Exporting a JavaScript React Class Component into a TypeScript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there a way to export a **JavaScript React Class Component** into a **TypeScript file**?

I have the following code:

**Login.js**

```
class Login extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.usernameText = React.createRef();
    this.passwordText = React.createRef();
    this.urlText = React.createRef();
    this.keyPress = this.keyPress.bind(this);
  }

  .
  .   
  .
 }
 export default  Login;
```

**index.ts**

```
const Login = require("./uiManagement/jiraUI/Login/Login");
export {
 Login as JiraUiLogin 
}
```

In another project i did an **`npm import`** for the above to use the login component:

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { JiraUiLogin } from "infosysta-typescript-core";
class mLogin extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <JiraUiLogin />
    )
  }
};
export default mLogin
```

But I'm having the following error:
[image]

Comment: what is the value of `moduleResolution` property in your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: in the core project is:   "moduleResolution": "node",

Comment: There might be wrong path in index.ts then. Please check the path first

Comment: ```const Login = require("./uiManagement/jiraUI/Login/Login.js");``` try adding the extension, if that doesn't work use import instead of require

Comment: Any chance you can share your `tsconfig.json` with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about changing the Login.js file to typescript?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

interface Props {
}
interface State {

}

class Login extends Component<Props, State> {
  usernameText = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  passwordText = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  urlText = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  keyPress = (event: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    
  };
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: that's what i did eventually and i used rollup to export my library and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to add `"allowJs": true` in the `compilerOptions` of your tsconfig file, and use an import statement instead of require.